# Problem getting the top product in each State

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

Hi I'm trying to get the top product in each State and not the top products regardless of State. I cant figure out what's missing in my query

[image: top products by count]

```
select State,ProductName,sum(Quantity) from orders group by State,ProductName order by sum(Quantity) desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to get the "groupwise maximum". Solution depends on the database system you are using, but in standard SQL (and Spark SQL) you could try an approach like:

```
WITH orders_cte AS
 (SELECT State, ProductName, SUM(Quantity) q,
         RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY State ORDER BY SUM(Quantity) DESC) ranking
    FROM orders
   GROUP BY State, ProductName)
SELECT State, ProductName, q
  FROM orders_cte 
 WHERE ranking = 1
```

Comment: thank you very much. was able to understand it well